# Magento 2 : set custom price in product when add to cart

Tags: magento2, event-observer, price

I see some answers about set custom price in product when add to cart.

But, I can't still solve my issue. I used observer for that to set custom price.

But, it's not working.

Can anyone please help me to solve it?

My code :

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
    $itemProId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $custom_price = $product->getPrice() + 10;
    $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't return anything in your observer code. So, it's not update product price.

Make sure that you use **checkout_cart_product_add_after** event.

**=> events.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="custom_price_cart_add_after" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\CustomPriceCartAddAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**=> CustomPriceCartAddAfter.php (Observer File) :**

Add ***return $this*** object at the end of your code inside

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
    $itemProId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $custom_price = $product->getPrice() + 10;
    $item->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Happy coding :)